# Error loading Partial View script (file: ~/Views/MacroPartials/Gallery.cshtml) in Umbraco project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, jquery-plugins, lightbox, umbraco7

Currently working on a project in Umbraco. Where I created a gallery using partial macro views. I tried to beautify the gallery by using lightbox plugin. I copied css file in css folder, images in images folder, js file in scripts folder from lightbox plugin. But while clicking gallery page it throw following error:

Error loading Partial View script (file: ~/Views/MacroPartials/Gallery.cshtml)

Comment: That error message is super generic and doesn't say anything useful. Did the partial view work before you "beautified" it? Then ry to un-beautify it again and make the changes step by step so you can pinpoint the actual error source.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just an error/bug in the Gallery.cshtml

You found the reason in the log file
goto: `\App_Data\Logs\UmbracoTraceLog.txt`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that view is missing a @using block

```
@using Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels
```

There should be a generated Image class in your App_Data\Models folder